# MYSQL: Using GROUP BY with string literals

Tags: string, mysql, query-string, pattern-matching

I have the following table with these columns:

```
shortName, fullName, ChangelistCount
```

Is there a way to group them by a string literal within their fullName? The fullname represents file directories, so I would like to display results for certain parent folders instead of the individual files.

I tried something along the lines of:

```
GROUP BY fullName like "%/testFolder/%" AND fullName like "%/testFolder2/%"
```

However it only really groups by the first match....

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like:

```
GROUP BY IF(fullName LIKE '%/testfolder/%', 1, IF(fullName LIKE '%/testfolder2/%', 2, 3))
```

The key idea to understand is that an expression like `fullName LIKE foo AND fullName LIKE bar` is that the entire expression will necessarily evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so you can only get two total groups out of that.

Using an `IF` expression to return one of *several* different values will let you get more groups.

Keep in mind that this will not be particularly fast. If you have a very large dataset, you should explore other ways of storing the data that will not require `LIKE` comparisons to do the grouping.

Comment: Hmm... I have to make multiple IFs so it seems perhaps rethinking the problem may be the best solution. Do you know of a good way to Group By date as well (perhaps by month for instance)?

Comment: Yes, you would have to nest the `IF` statements as I demonstrated in my example. MySQL has many date functions built in, including `MONTH()`.

Comment: Decided to leave the nested IF. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to use a subquery to derive the column values you'd like to ultimately group on:

```
    FROM (SELECT SUBSTR(fullname, ?)AS derived_column
            FROM YOUR_TABLE ) x
GROUP BY x.derived_column
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use when/then conditions or Have another temporary table containing all the matches you wish to find and group. Sample from my database.

Here I wanted to group all users based on their cities which was inside address field.

```
SELECT ut.* , c.city, ua.*
FROM  `user_tracking` AS ut
LEFT JOIN cities AS c ON ut.place_name LIKE CONCAT(  "%", c.city,  "%" )
LEFT JOIN users_auth AS ua ON ua.id = ut.user_id
```