# Grouping alike strings to gather using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

Below is a snapshot of the records in table and want to transfer from this

```
| Date     | Column1| Column2 | Column3
---------------------------------------
| 2016-01  | 10 HOME| X       | 20
| 2016-01  | HOME   | X       | 30
| 2016-01  | HOME,CA| X       | 30
| 2016-01  | PRES,TX| X       | 100
| 2016-01  | PRES,01| X       | 70
| 2016-01  | 40 PRES| X       | 30
| 2016-01  | FACTO  | X       | 10
| 2016-01  | FACTO,M| X       | 30
```

to this

```
| Date     | Column1| Column2 | Column3
---------------------------------------
| 2016-01  | HOME   | X       | 80
| 2016-01  | PRES   | X       | 200
| 2016-01  | FACTO  | X       | 40
```

The set of desired strings into which the alike strings are grouped is fixed that is for example in this case it is the set {"HOME","PRES","FACTO"}. The requirement is to group all the alike looking strings into one, that is the strings "10 HOME","HOME" and "HOME,CA" as just "HOME" in the group resultant table. I was looking into some of the threads like [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918122/mysql-using-group-by-with-string-literals) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951157/if-in-select-statement-choose-output-value-based-on-column-values) but still didn't get a solution, any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're going to have to be able to define "alike looking", not only for people here to be able to offer a solution, but for you to have any chance of implementing one.

Comment: @Tom: I have added definition of alike looking strings. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, "alike looking" means that it contains any of the strings that you've listed? Where do those strings come from?

Comment: @Tom: I have to feed this information into the query while grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get your search strings into a table then this becomes somewhat easier. I don't use MySQL much any more, so I don't recall what's available as far as table-valued parameters, temporary tables, or arrays, but something like the following would work:

```
SELECT
    MT.some_date,
    COALESCE(ST.search_string, MT.column_1) AS my_group,
    MT.column_2,
    SUM(MT.column_3)
FROM
    My_Table MT
LEFT OUTER JOIN Search_Table ST ON MT.column_1 LIKE '%' + ST.search_string + '%'
GROUP BY
    MT.some_date,
    COALESCE(ST.search_string, MT.column_1) AS my_group,
    MT.column_2
```

Some notes:

You'll want to actually use descriptive column names. I'm hoping that your column names above are just for the example.

This approach will break down if you have a search string that is contained within another search string. For example, "Bookstores" and "Books". Coding around that kind of situation will be very difficult regardless of your approach I think.

The search table is just a single column table with the strings that constitute your groups.

The `COALESCE` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s are to handle those situations where you have rows of data that don't fall into any group. They will appear as their own group. To eliminate those, just remove the `COALESCE` and change the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks. I looking into this solution, will try and let you know in sometime.